# Unity windows store app command line build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a build by command line for WSA and not succeeding. I've tried with another project to make it for a windows standalone version and it's working.

Here is the command line:

> C:\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -nographics -batchmode -projectPath "path
>   to project" -logFile "path to the file" -executeMethod
>   BuildScript.BuildGame

The BuildGame method is like this:

```
public static void BuildGame() {

   string[] scenes = new string[] { "path to scene one",
                "path to scene two" };
   BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, "path to the build\\Build.sln", BuildTarget.WSAPlayer, BuildOptions.None);

}
```

The weird thing is that the log says the compilation was successful, but it's not generating anything.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Code looks OK. However, it's possible that something is going wrong midway. remove the batchMode argument, or see if Unity is returning code 1 (It'll throw this if there's an error while executing in batchMode). Also, check your paths. I generally use / instead of \ in Unity. (\ needs to be escaped!). If you can post the complete command line, I could take a look

Comment: Thanks! The problem was with the path, I removed the "Build.sln" and I chose a folder inside the project's root and it worked.